# How can I count the number of elements that are in the particular zone?

Tags: python, pygame

I have 4 surface objects - items and one surface - backpack. When the item is on the backpack, it is considered to be *in* the backpack and it is counted. How can I do this? I need to know what items in particular are in the backpack

```
count = set()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                for num, item in enumerate(items):
                    if item.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        active_item = num
                    if item.collidepoint((450, 200)):
                        count.add(active_item)
                        print(len(count))
```